# Angular material animation - matRipple: escapes bounds of a div element

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, angular-material2

I've just added matRipple property to my div like:

```
<div matRipple class='icon-wrapper'>
  ...
</div>
```

[image: ripple animation]

Red border is actual size of the div element. As you can see, ripple animation escapes bounds of the div element.
How to hide overflowed ripple animation? `overflow: hidden` has no effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.icon-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

[link to issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4275)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 overflow: hidden !important
```

Comment: the result is same, no changes